# Pivot Table shows blank value labels

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have a pivot table which ideally I would like to exclude any row labels that have empty values. The pivot table can be seen below:

[image]

As can be seen in the image, there is no values for the row label Type 2.

For some reason the option to display these items is checked and grayed out in the pivot table options under the display tab as can be seen here:

[image]

I found a number of resources online that said to check the "show items with no data" field under the Layout & print tab in field settings, but still to no avail.

[image]

Basically I want to have the above pivot table to display Type 1 and Type 3 values but not Type 2 as it has no values.

I am using Excel 2010.

Any help on this matter would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can whoever down voted this post please explain why. I am new here and will gladly correct anything in the original post if needs be. Just looking for some help on this.

Comment: I wasn't the one who downvoted, but my assumption would be *(and I have a similar inkling about your question)* that  you just described what your error/issue is, but provided no way of reproducing the issue, no visual examples whatsoever and only a very barebones description . It's very hard to give a practical answer to a question asked in theoretical fashion - Update your question with [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and I could see this becoming a legitimate question

Comment: Thank you @Rawrplus for your advice. Do you think this is a more appropriately worded question now?

Comment: Yes, thank you for the edit. Upvoted now

Comment: Where would be a more suitable place to ask this @pnuts